# jQuery UI accordion on an ordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to incorporate some jQuery UI components into my company's html output for user documentation. I have very little experience with javascript. I got accordion to work for table rows but now I want to expand and collapse substeps under a step so an ordered list inside an ordered list but cannot seem to get it to work. Sorry if the answer is simple but PLEASE HELP ME!!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
 $(function() {
 $(".sub li:not(.accordion)").hide();
 $(".sub li:first-child").show();

 $(".sub li.accordion").click(function(){
     $(this).nextAll("li").fadeToggle(500);
 }).eq(0).trigger('click');
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ol class="sub">
            <li class="accordion">Section 1</li>
            <ol>
            <li>Description</li>
            <li>This is text within section 1.</li>
            </ol>
            <li class="accordion">Section 2</li>
            <ol>
                <li>Description</li>
                <li>This is text within section 2.</li>
            </ol>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it initially supposed to show just "Section 1" and "Section 2", and when you click on each one it displays substeps?

Comment: Yes, I know the example isn't the best but when you click on section 1 or section 2 it displays the ordered list under it. It should display 1. Section 1 and have 1. Description and 2. This is text within section 1 under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to  have the correct page markup in order for accordion to work:
http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

Shortly, each sector's header should be wrapped in `<h>` tag and its content in a `<div>`, in your case:

```
<ol class="sub">
    <li class="accordion">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div>
            <ol>
                <li>Description</li>
                <li>This is text within section 1.</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion">
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
            <ol>
                <li>Description</li>
                <li>This is text within section 2.</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

And now just tell JQuery that the main `<ol>` is an accordion:

```
$(".sub").accordion()
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d5WzS/1/).

Comment: Ok but how do I get the ordered list headers to have have numbers?

Comment: They are removed by CSS classes, which are added once you apply `.accordion()` to the element. To have them back, you need to tell CSS not to override the `list-style-type` and `padding` properties. 
To do so, just add following CSS rules to your `.sub` class: 
`.sub {list-style-type: decimal !important; padding-left: 40px !important}`

But I recommend you add numbers to the headers manually.